# Sigalrm (linux signal)

Tags: linux, posix, boost-signals2

I'm new to Linux signals. If a process initializes multiple timers,
then how does a process know which `SIGALRM` belongs to which timer?

Answer (score 1):

It depends how you set up your `SIGALRM` handler.

Consider also using not `alarm` but [timer_create](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_create.2.html) or even [timerfd_create(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timerfd_create.2.html) (with `poll`).

If you call [sigaction(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) with the `SA_SIGINFO` you get the `siginfo_t` which indirectly gives you the timer information.

Read also [all about linux signals](https://web.archive.org/web/20211028010349/https://www.linuxprogrammingblog.com/all-about-linux-signals), and [Advanced Linux Programming](https://web.archive.org/web/20170903154201/http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)